# an expression of the discriminant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $δ := det((X_i^{j−1} ) 1\le i,j \le n ) ∈ \mathbb{Z}[X_1 , · · · , X_n ]$.

## Let $δ = \sum_{ν∈\mathbb{N}^n} a_\nu X^\nu$ .

prove that $a_\nu \ne 0 ⇒ \sum_{i=1}^n \nu_i = n(n − 1)/2$.

I don't understand the expression in bold. What does $X^\nu$ represent?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It follows [this notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation). Specifically, $X^{\nu}:=X_1^{\nu_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n^{\nu_n}$.